# read sms data of an iphone in a mac app when connected

Tags: macos, sms, jailbreak, ios5

I need to develop a mac app that reads and shows all the text messages that iPhone has. I know about the privacy issues and all and have also tried to read the sms.db file using `sqlite_open` command; it gave me `SQLITE_AUTH` error.

Now my question is How did the PhoneView people did it?

Check out these urls:

1. http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/quicktour.html?show=4
2. http://www.wondershare.com/data-recovery/iphone-data-recovery.html

Although both of the apps are not on Mac App Store, so I am assuming Apple might have rejected it. But even then I would like to know how these people did it.

Answer (score 0):

They probably used libimobiledevice library http://www.libimobiledevice.org/